# best way to made changes in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, search, catalogsearch

I create a custom theme and I want to change this file: `module-search/view/frontend/template/form.mini.phtml`

To be safe I need to move this file in my custom theme? If yes what will be the correct path in my theme folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you ought to override the template using your theme. [Lots of useful theme structure info here in the devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html#info) so definitely read up on that.

In this particular case you need to place your template in the folder following this structure: `<Vendor>_<Module>/templates` so it would be `Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.phtml`